# Constructors for derived classes must contain a 'super' call. ts(2377)

Tags: typescript

This is not the usual problem with a missing `super()` call. Instead I have a special construct where I need to call `super()` differently. Check this code:

```js
class A {
    public constructor() {
        console.log("c-tor A");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public constructor(s: string);
    public constructor(i: number, s: string);
    public constructor(_i: string | number, s?: string) {
        const x = () => {
            s = "";
            super();
        };

        x();
        console.log("c-tor B");
    }
}

const b = new B("");
```

It runs fine and prints:

> c-tor A
> c-tor B

However, tsc reports the error mentioned in the title:

[image]

and I cannot suppress it by using `// @ts-ignore`. What other option do I have to silence the compiler?

Comment: What is the purpose for that structure?

Comment: It's part of a new tool which will translate Java to TS and will handle socalled "explicit constructor invocation" (the `this()` call in a constructor), by calling that closure from within the closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@ts-ignore` does the job, but your problem is that es-lint is also complaining. You will need to add `eslint-disable constructor-super`

```
class B extends A {
    public constructor(s: string);
    public constructor(i: number, s: string);
    /* eslint-disable constructor-super */
    /* @ts-ignore */
    public constructor(_i: string | number, public s?: string) {
        const x = () => {
            s = '';
            // @ts-ignore
            super();
        };

        x();
        console.log('c-tor B');
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XQA4FcBGICWw0wA9gHYQAuATpsBcVQBQCUiKaHJ5xIApgHQhiAc0YAiYAFp6VOGOYBudqgC%20SNUlCQYAIWi8AHhV6kAJjHjIOWXASJlKNOg0YQAXNEd5Swxcow4%20IRcjrQyjHgepJgAtti8VAA0nh5ePn4cAPSZAAIUEJJ4wqQMvP42Qfbk1GEuAPqRntTewtAAPtDRcQnJFXYQAPypzelsHJwOFNAG0AC80CxzAHxj42sw82JiSmtr2XkFRSVUZbvjEJjoCSw7uypK-hwGN49oITwCQqIS0gzQOvJbqp1EhNJNoNg5p1eAB3f7iQFAA)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
class B extends A {
    public constructor(s: string);
    public constructor(i: number, s: string);
    // @ts-ignore
    public constructor(_i: string | number, s?: string) {
        const x = () => {
            s = "";
            // @ts-ignore
            super();
        };

        x();
        console.log("c-tor B");
    }
}
```

You need to ignore the entire constructor and also the call to `super` inside your function as TS doesn't like this.